# Image as camera foreground

Tags: camera, image

I am trying to see an image through the camera as *foreground* of the render (i.e., the 3D model is visible through transparent parts), but I only find ways to insert an image as background (i.e., the 3D model is OVER it).
Is there a way to do this? I mean in the viewport, not in the final render (in that case, I can easily composite the image with an alpha over).

Comment: You should always include information about what render engine you are using when asking questions about rendering or shading functionality. Also your goals should be defined clearly. It is not clear what kind of image you are talking about. Should it move with the camera? Is it 360 degree panoramic image? You can use textured geometry parented (or constrained other way) to the camera.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I was thinking that the rendering engine is not important since I am talking about the viewport. However, I am currently using Eevee. I am referring to an image taken from a normal camera (with a green screen, actually), not 360 degrees. Parenting a textured plane is a good solution, but I was wondering if there is a quicker way (in a way similar to the camera background image).

Comment: I don't think it gets any easier than a plane with an image. You can use Import Images as Planes add-on. it works in 2.80. Just don't forget to set the correct transparency blending mode for the transparency. It's ridiculously hidden in the Shader Editor's n panel under Settings as Blend Mode(at least in today's build).

Comment: Oh, OK, its just me, that's the same as material properties...

Comment: Yes thanks, I had only to do some math to understand the right size of the plane (in order to make it fit exactly with the camera near plane). In Eevee I had to put it as "background" and thus it made me choose the blend mode.